# Xamarin Visual Studio 15.6.2 creating a mobile app missing UI technology option

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Recently upgraded to the latest Visual Studio first 15.6.1 and then 15.6.2 from 15.4.2 as 15.4.2 was failing to build a release build for me of the app and builds in general were very unstable. I am working on as a proof of concept app.

An upgrade to the latest versions did not help, so I decided to create a smaller app that hopefully built and slowly add functionality to attempt to discover when the process fails. Creating a cross=platform, mobile app, now failed to show the option for UI technology and is then missing all the required references for Xamarin.Forms. I do not see, anywhere that this is a new Feature, so I assume this is a bug.

[image: Image of the Xamarin mobile app template]

Comment: what is your issue? Since VS 2017 15.5 the PCL is deprecated and replaced with .net standard. What was broken for 15.4?

Comment: Copying from my question "now failed to show the option for UI technology". The issue is nothing to do with .net standard replacing PCL. All the current versions of Xamarin show all three option. With out Xamarin.Forms set there are a number of references missing

Comment: i still have no idea what you want? the checkbox for native or xamarin.forms?

Comment: Indeed, that is what, I am looking for

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94216/unable-to-create-cross-platform-portable-project-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: i Have the same issue no option to choose `native` only `xamarin.forms` i'm on `15.6.2` but i can confirm it also exist in `15.6.1`

Comment: @Kemen, did you find out how to fix this?